# height() issue, Chrome zoom makes viewheight value have a decimal (annoying scrollbar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, vertical-scrolling

Because i use a horizontal website it requires me to use a .height() script to tell the view height of the browser and so the content height within.
Using Chrome on 125% zoom gives a weird result, making my viewheight of the HTML *773.6 px*. [JSFiddle .value example](https://jsfiddle.net/807/oavp8v3n/).

> $(window).height();

result is: *774 px* , which adds a pixel to the html, **making a annoying vertical scrollbar appair**.

```
Math.floor($(window).height());
```

the *.height()* script always rounds the value to a number without decimals, so i **can't** use *Math.floor()*.

i don't want to use *overflow-y: hidden;*

[JSFiddle horizontal template](https://jsfiddle.net/807/v0mjcLtq/).

Comment: Please can you explain, what for you need to detect the height and how you are using it then?

Comment: Thanks @Martin P for commenting, As i said above, i have a horizontal website (which means a horizontal scrollbar instead of a vertical one), horizontal websites are more difficult and require Javascript to work. I have a fixed header with a fixed height ,but the 100% height content below is behind the header(because its fixed) so i have to subtract the header height from the content div and give margin-top so its below the header. (i'm always open for ways to make it more easy). (I have to keep the question as clean and readable as possible so i cant add a lot of explanation)

Comment: I have added a template example in the post, try to zoom in Chrome (it works on 200% zoom for me in JSFiddle) and maby you see a Vertical scrollbar appear to.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the header bar has a fixed height!? Then there is no problem using classic methods. If the header-height is flexible, i would use flexbox. But it depends on which browsers you'd like to cover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
.wrap {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  }

header {
  background: red;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  }

main {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>Test</header>
  <main>Content</main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for making a example @Martin P, but this isn't a horizontal scrolling example. When i change the width to lets say 10000px and a long content there is still is a vertical scrollbar showing up and the header moving.

Comment: Uhm, that's clear  :)  you have to put overflow-x hidden to the main element. I can't show you the whole example. I think you have to give more details if you want to receive a more detailed answer. But there is no problem using my wrapper-snippet for a vertical scrolling website.